# MySql SumIF from another table without changing the order of the values

Tags: mysql

I hope anyone can help me in this task, so i have 2 tables in a MySql Database:

```
Table1
+------+------------+
| Name |    Data    |
+------+------------+
| b    | 2018-11-01 |
| c    | 2018-11-01 |
| a    | 2018-11-01 |
| d    | 2018-11-01 |
| e    | 2018-11-01 |
+------+------------+

Table2
+------+------------+------------+
| Name |   Value    |    Data    |
+------+------------+------------+
| b    | Imported   | 2018-11-01 |
| c    | Activation | 2018-11-01 |
| a    | Activation | 2018-11-01 |
| b    | Activation | 2018-11-01 |
| b    | Activation | 2018-11-01 |
| d    | Activation | 2018-11-01 |
| a    | Activation | 2018-11-01 |
+------+------------+------------+
```

The requested output is:

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Total |
+-------+-------+
| b     |     2 |
| c     |     1 |
| a     |     2 |
| d     |     1 |
| e     |     0 |
+-------+-------+
```

Note: The order of names in the requested table should be the same as in table1.

I can do a similar result with this query:

```
Select 
   t2.Name
 , SUM(IF(t2.Value != 'Imported, 1, 0)) Total
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE t2.Data = '2018-11-01'
GROUP BY t2.Name
```

But the result has not the same order of names as in Table1 but like this:

```
+-------+-------+
| Name  | Total |
+-------+-------+
| a     |     2 |
| b     |     2 |
| c     |     1 |
| d     |     1 |
| e     |     0 |
+-------+-------+
```

And that is the reason i need table1, only for the order of the names.

If anyone can help me please?

Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are only elements, you can use this simply:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(name, 'b,c,a,d,e');
```

Or you can also use:

[FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(name, 'b','c','a','d','e');
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i managed to resolve the problem with your suggestion, another question if it is possible. What about if 'b,c,a,d,e' is dynamic? SO in another scenario it can be 'a,c,b,d,e', should i use a subquery inside this function?